# Null pointer exception with tiles in MarioBros libgdx game

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, libgdx, tiles

I'm following the guide on how to make MarioBros in libgdx, you can find it on YouTube at the CodeSchool channel.
Unfortunately I'm stuck at lesson n°13, when he removes the tile of the cell containing the brick when Mario's head collides whit it, you can watch it at this youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Br9fF4xcL94&t=322s), minute 9'00".
When I type `getClass().setTile(null)`, I get a NullPointerException.
I tried to fix it in every kind of way but still without results.

```
public class Brick extends InteractiveTileObject
{
    public Brick(World world, TiledMap map, Rectangle bounds)
    {
        super(world, map, bounds);
        fixture.setUserData(this);
        setCategoryFilter(MyGdxGame.BRICK_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHeadHit() 
    {
        Gdx.app.log("Brick", "Collision");
        setCategoryFilter(MyGdxGame.DESTROYED_BIT);
        getCell().setTile(null);   //!!!!!!!
    }
}
```

This is the Stack trace:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.mygdx.game.Sprites.Brick.onHeadHit(Brick.java:29) at
>   com.mygdx.game.Tools.WorldContactListener.beginContact(World‌​ContactListener.java‌​:32)
>   at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.beginContact(World.java‌​:985)
>   at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniStep(Native Method) at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.step(World.java:689) at
>   com.mygdx.game.Screens.PlayScreen.update(PlayScreen.java:102‌​) at
>   com.mygdx.game.Screens.PlayScreen.render

I tried to call `getCell()` only and it works, but the brick that should disappear stays there... so I need to call `setTile(null)` on the getCell method, but when I try it throws a NPE.

This is the getCell() method:

```
public TiledMapTileLayer.Cell getCell()
{
    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(1);
    return layer.getCell((int) (body.getPosition().x * MyGdxGame.PPM / 16), (int) (body.getPosition().y * MyGdxGame.PPM / 16)); 
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you understand what a NullPointerException is? Also, post all relevant code here as text.

Comment: Done. Sorry but it's the first time i post something here

Comment: Np. When you post here, remember the easier to make it for people to help you, the more likely someone will be able to. With 1000s of new questions a day, if a question is too hard to make sense of, many people will just skip over it.

Comment: And do you have a stack trace for the NPE?

Comment: when calling `getCell()` , the result is `null`. If you attempt to call something on eg `null.<a method>(<arguments>)`, you will get `NullPointerException`

Comment: no, i tried to call getCell() only and it works, but the brick that should disappear stays there...
so i need to call setTile(null) on the getCell method, but when i try it throws a NPE.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your last two comments into the question. If you disagree with my edit, you can roll it back. To roll it back, click on the `edited ... ago` link. This takes you to the revision history of the question, where you can roll back to an earlier version.

Comment: I think @KarelG is right. You can call `getCell` independently. The fact that it returns `null` isn't a problem... _until_ you try to call a method on that return value. So - what is the return value of `getCell()`? Is it `null`, or is it something else?

Comment: Thank you Barth! I've just uploaded the getCell method code. The NPE happens when i work on the tile (TiledMapTile) of the user data

Comment: Hm, the top line of the stack trace is `onHeadHit`, not `getCell`. So I'm pretty sure that `getCell` is returning `null`. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with libgdx or this tutorial to see _why_ it returns `null`. You could try to split the expressions in `getCell`, and see what their intermediate results are. Maybe you're having a rounding error somewhere.